# "I could have lunch before you arrived."

Tags: past-tense, conditionals, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, french

I'm having a discussion on Duolingo about this sentence in French that translates into:

> I was able to have lunch before you arrived.

An alternate translation (also accepted by Duolingo) goes like this:

> I could have lunch before you arrived.

It sounds odd, and I would certainly never say it like that, but is the second (alternate) translation technically correct, since **could** is the preterite form of **can**?

EDIT: The original French version of the sentence is:

> *J'ai pu déjeuner avant que tu arrives.*

(The latter part is in subjunctive.)

Comment: It sounds so like 'I could have lunch before you arrive' that there is a temptation to see it as an error. Try 'I was right, there _was_ enough time: I _could_ have lunch (/ finish my homework) before you arrived!'

Comment: They are not the same.  The first means you, in fact, ***did*** have lunch, the second means that it hasn’t happened yet but it’s possible (and it would be better to make it ***arrive*** - without the ’d’ - in that case)

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding how the same sentence in French could translate into both of those. They are totally different. One is stating a past fact, the second is speculating about a future possibility. The latter is also ungrammatical. 'Arrived' cannot be in the past tense. Are you able to say what the French said?

Comment: @WS2 See Edwin’s comment. _Could_ can also mean ‘was able to [and successfully did]’ here, though it requires a fair amount of brain-forcing. I’m guessing the French would go something like, “J’ai pu [prendre mon] déjeuner avant que tu es arrivé”. I would agree that Duolingo would have done better not to accept _could_ here, since it requires such a very specific context to work at all, and even then is somewhat odd.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hmm, yes. I see entirely what you are saying. Some people might use 'could' in that way with past inference, but far more likely a person of average erudition would add a past marker such as 'I found I could have lunch before you arrived'. As it stands  I would not rate it as grammatical.

Comment: Perhaps, “I could have had lunch before you arrived”?  Je voudrais voir la version originale.

Comment: "could have had" definitely implies "didn't" to me

Comment: @AllenS. I've added the original, French version to the question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet As you point out by your "and successfully did", translation is tricky here because unlike Romance, English modals cannot via tense alone distinguish an imperfect past describing an historical condition and a completed past that’s all done with. Compare *“J’ai pu prendre mon déjeuner avant que tu sois arrivé”* (perfect=was able and did) with *“Je pouvais prendre mon déjeuner avant que tu sois arrivé, mais ce dont tu viens de m'informer a changé tout ça et maintenant je n'ai pas de faim.”* (imperfect=was able but in this case didn't).

Comment: @WS2 Oh, it can happen easily enough: *“J'ai pu”* and *“Je pouvais”* could easily both translate into the very same *“I could”* in English, for example. Yet the former in French’s *passé composé* says that I was able to and actually did so, while the latter in Frenchs *imparfait* doesn't say anything about whether you got around to doing so. Translators can often use a past progressive construction in English to pick up this nuance of the French imperfect, but not here because *I ⚹was being able to* isn’t grammatical in English.

Comment: @tchrist But wouldn't the difference between a past condition and a completed past be achieved through "I could have taken..." (past condition) and "I was able to take..." (completed past). But whereas in English the former tells the listener "but I didn't", the French *je pouvais prendre...* is neutral and says nothing about whether you did take. Is that what we are saying? Introduce another verb complement "I was being invited to take lunch..." which IS grammatical, and the neutrality is effected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was able to {have lunch} before you arrived

talks about past ability. You can change the sentence into an interrogative

> Were you able to {have lunch} before I arrived?

And your first sentence provides the answer.

The *could* equivalent is

> I could {have lunch} before you arrived.

This is a positive response to the question

> Could you {have lunch} before I arrived?

Before someone objects that the sentence is not natural, let’s look at two sentences with *could* where the meaning of past ability is plain and the sentences sounds more natural:

> I could guess your age/height/weight before you told me.

or

> I could guess the meaning of your riddle before you finished telling it.

Note that all these sentences talk strictly about past *ability*...they don’t necessarily say anything about whether the task was carried out. This can be seen by the following:

> I was able to have lunch before you arrived, but I didn’t (have lunch).
>
> I could have lunch before you arrived, but I didn’t (have lunch).

And the more natural sounding

> I could guess your age/height/weight before you told me, but I didn’t (guess it).
>
> I could guess the meaning of your riddle before you finished telling it, but I didn’t (guess it).

*I was able to* can be substituted for *I could* in the last two sentences.

So, yes, both sentences you ask about refer to past *ability*; they are equivalent in meaning. So the *could* sentences (declarative & interrogative) are  just as grammatical as the *was/were able to* sentences. And the declarative is a possible alternative translation.

Comment: To convey the "can and did" bit, sometimes a less literal word-for-word translation works better, with *“I managed to catch lunch before you got here”* being just one possible approach. Unfortunately one cannot hope for a computer program at Duolingo to support such liberties.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ça aide, merci! Oui, "avant que" prend le subjonctif.

The English literal rendition illustrates the challenge of translation:  "I could have lunched before you arrive."  The equivalent sentiment expressed in American English is "I was able to have lunch before your arrival."

Comment: Do you mean that the usual interpretation of the French original is that the possible past-tense lunch did occur?

Comment: Yes,  The part of the French sentence, word-for-word, that forms the first clause is:  I (Je, but in French a terminating vowel is dropped when followed by a word beginning with a vowel)/ have (ai) /past participle of "pouvoir", "to be able to", or "can" or "may"/avant ("before")/que ("that")/tu ("you" informal form/arrives (arrive--subjunctive case).  The difficulty arises from the fact that in French there is a present subjunctive case and a past tense of the subjunctive.  The problem is that modern speakers don't often use the past subjunctive, so it could be "arrive" or "arrived".

Comment: The context, however, makes it clear that "arrived" is implied,